# Return types analysis of a method updating an object

Tags: java, oop

What is the difference between the following 2 approaches to defining a return type for a method which updates an object? (void vs Foo)

The first one:

```
void updateSomeFields(final Foo foo){
    foo.setBar(fancyProcessing(foo.getBar())); // and more
}
```

And the second one:

```
Foo updateSomeFields(final Foo foo){
    foo.setBar(fancyProcessing(foo.getBar())); // and more
    return foo;
}
```

None of these methods be defined inside Foo.

---

- Is one of the differences related to procedural vs OOP style (1 vs 2)?
- Java allows the values of the object's fields to be changed in the method (i.e. allows 1. to work).  But should they be changed in such a case?
- Does it ever make sense to define a local Foo in approach 2?

---

### Update

Based on lead from Andy Turner on [fluent interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) (object oriented API that aims to provide more readable code) it has answered:

Does it ever make sense to define a local Foo in approach 2?
**Local variable declarations are syntactic sugar because of the difficulty humans have with deeply nested method calls.**

It is useful  for method cascading (concretely method chaining) to relay the instruction context of a subsequent call , however in the scope of this question having the methods outside Foo itself perhaps the return type would be neither Foo nor void but the containing helper class.

Comment: Sidenote i found useful - While chaining is syntax, it has semantic consequences, namely that requires methods to return an object, and if implementing cascading via chaining, this must be the current object. This prevents the return value from being used for some other purpose, such as returning an error value.

Comment: "this must be the current object" Not true, e.g. look at methods on `BigDecimal`, e.g. [`BigDecimal.add`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java#1016): this returns neither the current instance nor the argument.

Comment: @AndyTurner however it does return BigDecimal. To be precise, the phrase can be updated to "this must be the current object's class" , which is what I actually had in mind

Comment: That is incorrect too. You are trying to formalize rules that just don't exist: the return type of a method can be anything that is appropriate to the purpose of the method. Sometimes that will be the same type as the current instance; when it is so, the returned value may or may not be the current instance. (Many/most) other times, it will be a different type.

Comment: No need to be sorry, we all want to expand our knowledge here. Thought this to be useful. If you feel charitable you might as well try to update the wikipedia page @AndyTurner https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach No.2 makes it easier to set multiple attributes in single statement
like `Bar.setFoo(foo).setFoo1(foo1)` and so on

I prefer Approach2 just because it offers extra flexibility

**Update:** 
This principle violates Java Bean spec so `JSP's` and other `Spring` stuff could break

Also see [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

> A fluent interface is normally implemented by using method cascading (concretely method chaining) to relay the instruction context of a subsequent call

Comment: I'm not asking in the context of a builder pattern.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. then returning the same object makes no sense. Return void.

Comment: Well, the question is why it does not make sense. I am looking for arguments favouring one approach or the other. A friend came up with a justification in programming style (those coming from a procedural background and still applying the style to java). I'm looking for others or more.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. it's not a builder pattern - it is a fluent API. There is nothing that says that a builder has to be implemented fluently, nor is there anything that says that a fluent API is a builder. However, builders are *commonly* implemented as fluent APIs because it is convenient to invoke multiple setters without needing a local variable.